# Angular show components between table rows

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a table view inside a component that has rows rendered with *ngFor directive. When user clicks on a specific row, I want to show a child component below this row. Following is my code.

```
<tbody>
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items" >
<tr (click)="expand(item)">
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  <td>{{item.title}}</td>  
  <td>{{item.description}}</td>
</tr>
<tr *ngIf="isexpanded(item)">
  <app-item-comp [item]="item"></app-item-comp>
</tr>
</ng-container>
```

This will show the child component app-item-comp when I click on a row. But its width is same as the first element of the row rather than taking the entire window. I want to view this child component having the full width of the table. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: If `app-item-comp` 'returns' a `td` (`th`) element, try [colspan attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_colspan.asp)

Comment: In my child component, I have another table.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Consider below code is in you ts file

let items: any = [
    {
        itemName: 'ABC',
        itemId: '1',
        isSubRowDisplayed: false
    },
    {
        itemName: 'PQR',
        itemId: '2',
        isSubRowDisplayed: false
    },
    {
        itemName: 'MNO',
        itemId: '3',
        isSubRowDisplayed: false
    }
];

expand(clickedItem: any): any {
    clickedItem.isSubRowDisplayed = !clickedItem.isSubRowDisplayed;
}
```

```html
<tbody>
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items" >
<tr (click)="expand(item)">
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  <td>{{item.title}}</td>  
  <td>{{item.description}}</td>
</tr>
<tr *ngIf="item?.isSubRowDisplayed">
  <app-item-comp [item]="item"></app-item-comp>
</tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I want a way to show the child component, having the same width as the main table. This does not answer for that.

Comment: @NirmalGamage, I think this will be possible by having two different CSS classes. One CSS class will be applied when isSubRowDisplayed = false and other will be when isSubRowDisplayed = true. Now when we click on particular row either we will have to set width for entire table or row. By using [ngClass] you can achieve it.